# How do I use "plus" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, conjunctions, commas

I am trying to express this sentence.

> He doesn't have the key to the storage room ***plus*** he doesn't even know where it is.

Do I need to add a comma before the conjunction "plus", or is this fine as it is.

I know that using "plus" as a conjunction is informal; therefore, what other words could be used there in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inference of using 'plus', rather than just using 'and', is that it suggests an *additional* point or an afterthought rather than just joining two equal points together.

For that reason, I would expect to see a comma as a pause in speech.

> He doesn't have the key to the storage room, plus he doesn't even know where it is.

I wouldn't say that 'plus' is strictly 'informal', just that it tends to be used in informal speech rather than in writing for the reason I've already given - it introduces additional points or afterthoughts. If you were writing a list of points or reasons you would think more about how to present and weigh them. But alternatives to it could be '*also*', or '*additionally*'.

Comment: Comma before plus, exactly what I needed to know, upvoted and accepted

Comment: [Moreover](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moreover) is another possibility.